# If i already added a list1 into the list1array, how to prevent the exact same list1 from being added

Tags: java, collections

For my problem, when I already added a question("where am i?") into the array, when it loopback and asked for another question input, if i input the exact same question("where am i?), it will still prompt me to write an answer instead of saying that the question is asked before. I want it to reply the question is asked before instead of continuing the loop to ask question.

```
public void botaddquestion(){
    do{
        Scanner user = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("[AI] Question input ==>");
        input = user.nextLine();
        if(!input.equals("end")){
            questionarray.add(input);
            System.out.print("[AI] Answer input ==>");
            answerarray.add(user.nextLine());
        }else if(!questionarray.equals(input)){
                System.out.println("This question has been asked before");
        }
    }while(!input.equals("end"));
    System.out.println("[AI] <[END]>");
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("[AI] Script given");
    for(int i=0; i<questionarray.size(); i++){
        System.out.println(("[AI] Question given is '" +questionarray.get(i))+"'");
        System.out.println(("[AI] Answer given is '" +answerarray.get(i))+"'");
    }
        System.out.println("");
}
```

Comment: Just add a check if the list already exist if it doesn't then add else do nothing

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the [`contains`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#contains-java.lang.Object-) method:

```
} else if (questionarray.contains(input)) {
    // Here -------------^
    System.out.println("This question has been asked before");
}
```

Comment: this is not the only needed change to fix program. duplicated questions will still be added to list. see my answer for more details

Answer (score 0):

Your if statement should be sorted and check

```
    if (questionarray.contains(input)){
        System.out.println("This question has been asked before");            
    } else if(!input.equals("end")){
        questionarray.add(input);
        System.out.print("[AI] Answer input ==>");
        answerarray.add(user.nextLine());                
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. use a Set (HashSet or TreeSet depending if sorting is important to you or not) instead of List.
2. Your "else if" regarding validation of question already present should be before the your if regarding !end, since that second if is the one actually adding the value to the array and you want to prevent that.
3. Your validation is wrong, you should not do an equals between the list and the input string. That will never be equals. Instead use a contains call (method from Set interface)

Answer (score 0):

questionarray seems to be a list. So you should write :

```
System.out.print("[AI] Question input ==>");
input = user.nextLine();
if(input.equals("end")){
    break;
}
if(questionarray.constains(input)){
    System.out.println("This question has been asked before");
    continue;
}
questionarray.add(input);
System.out.print("[AI] Answer input ==>");
answerarray.add(user.nextLine());
```

Answer (score 0):

You use a `HashSet` to store this question strings. Here is a demo,

```
 Set set = new HashSet<String>();
 System.out.println(set.add("hello"));
 System.out.println(set.add("hello"));
```

Output:

```
true
false
```